# Phpmyadmin timestamp currenttimestamp

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I've set my date_added column to timestamp and default value to current_timestamp.

Does this mean each new row the date_added value will automatically be the current timestamp?

For example: Comments table.

> comment_id{PK][AI],user_id[FK],content,date_added

Every new comment i insert, i also need to add in a date for when it was posted so when viewing the comment i can print out an " months/hours ago" using `timespan();`in CI.

```
$now = time();
$data['user_id'] = $user_id;
$data['content'] = $content;
$data['date_added'] = mdate("%Y-%m-%d h:i:a",$now);
$this->db->insert('comments',$data);
```

instead i can just remove the date added part.

This should be a shortcut to manually inserting the current time via date_helper in CI whenever i insert a new row. However, i would like to ask if my logic is correct or if i am misusing the current_timestamp function of phpmyadmin?

Comment: Correct, each new row will be filled with the current timestamp

Comment: In your view, am i misusing the phpmyadmin function for my laziness? or is it a sound logic?

Comment: No, not lazy, it's a convenience in my point of view..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `current_timestamp` is not a function of phpmyadmin, it's a feature of MySQL.  It's not lazy, it's perfectly acceptable to use it in the way you are.